# Finding a specific sentence in string

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm working in WinForms.
I have a very large string, And I want that the string will only contain sentences with some specific words.
I tried to use some methods but they didnt work for me.
Does somebody has an idea?

For example, I have this String:

```
 "warnings": [
        "INFORMATION FOR THE PATIENT 10 mL Vial (1000 Units per vial) WARNINGS THIS LILLY HUMAN INSULIN PRODUCT DIFFERS FROM ANIMAL–SOURCE INSULINS BECAUSE IT IS STRUCTURALLY IDENTICAL TO THE INSULIN PRODUCED BY YOUR BODY’S PANCREAS AND BECAUSE OF ITS UNIQUE MANUFACTURING PROCESS. ANY CHANGE OF INSULIN SHOULD BE MADE CAUTIOUSLY AND ONLY UNDER MEDICAL SUPERVISION. CHANGES IN STRENGTH, MANUFACTURER, TYPE (E.G., REGULAR, NPH, ANALOG), SPECIES, OR METHOD OF MANUFACTURE MAY RESULT IN THE NEED FOR A CHANGE IN DOSAGE. SOME PATIENTS TAKING HUMULIN® (HUMAN INSULIN, rDNA ORIGIN) MAY REQUIRE A CHANGE IN DOSAGE FROM THAT USED WITH OTHER INSULINS. IF AN ADJUSTMENT IS NEEDED, IT MAY OCCUR WITH THE FIRST DOSE OR DURING THE FIRST SEVERAL WEEKS OR MONTHS. DIABETES Insulin is a hormone produced by the pancreas, a large gland that lies near the stomach. This hormone is necessary for the body’s correct use of food, especially sugar. Diabetes occurs when the pancreas does not make enough insulin to meet your body’s needs. To control your diabetes, your doctor has prescribed injections of insulin products to keep your blood glucose at a near–normal level. You have been instructed to test your blood and/or your urine regularly for glucose. Studies have shown that some chronic complications of diabetes such as eye disease, kidney disease, and nerve disease can be significantly reduced if the blood sugar is maintained as close to normal as possible. The American Diabetes Association recommends that if your pre–meal glucose levels are consistently above 130 mg/dL or your hemoglobin A1c (HbA1c) is more than 7%, you should talk to your doctor. A change in your diabetes therapy may be needed. If your blood tests consistently show below–normal glucose levels, you should also let your doctor know. Proper control of your diabetes requires close and constant cooperation with your doctor. Despite diabetes, you can lead an active and healthy life if you eat a balanced diet, exercise regularly, and take your insulin injections as prescribed by your doctor. Always keep an extra supply of insulin as well as a spare syringe and needle on hand. Always wear diabetic identification so that appropriate treatment can be given if complications occur away from home."
      ],
```

I've tried this method, but it doesnt fit to my wishes:

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd)
        {
            int Start=0, End=0;
            
            if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
            {
                
                    Start += strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0)+strStart.Length;
                    End += strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
           
                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }


        }
```

I also tried to change it but it didnt work:

```
public static string getBetween(string strSource, string strStart, string strEnd, string mid)
        {
            int Start=0, End=0;
            Boolean check = false;
            
            if (strSource.Contains(strStart) && strSource.Contains(strEnd))
            {
                while (check == false)
                {
                    Start += strSource.IndexOf(strStart, 0) + strStart.Length;
                    End += strSource.IndexOf(strEnd, Start);
                    if (strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start).Contains(mid))
                    { check = true; }
                }

                return strSource.Substring(Start, End - Start);
            }
            else
            {
                return "";
            }


        }
```

I want only sentences with the word `blood` to be shown in the `RickTextBox`.

Thanks

Comment: Please post what you've tried and include a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Please, post an example of a sentence, and what you've tried. Contains should be more than enough.

Comment: @ronfl What happens when you run that code? Are you wanting all sentences that contain blood or that start with blood?

Comment: @Dispersia   the problem is that this method is getting a start, end. And I want star, end, between them I need to check if the word exists, so I edited the method but it still doesnt working.

Comment: Ok, we can do this for the most part, but how do you define a sentence, do you want to get between periods? What if it's like Dr. Stein, or Ms. Napier.

Comment: @Dispersia I define a sentence by starting with a ".", and ending with "."/"?"/"!"

Comment: @ronfl See ex: `blah blah. It costs $2.5 .`. What is second sentence `It costs $2` ? :)

Comment: @ronfl Did any of these answers solve your dilemma?

Answer (score 1):

#### This is a way to do it using RegEx:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string source= "INFORMATION FOR THE PATIENT 10 mL Vial (1000 Units per vial) WARNINGS THIS LILLY HUMAN INSULIN PRODUCT DIFFERS FROM ANIMAL–SOURCE INSULINS BECAUSE IT IS STRUCTURALLY IDENTICAL TO THE INSULIN PRODUCED BY YOUR BODY’S PANCREAS AND BECAUSE OF ITS UNIQUE MANUFACTURING PROCESS. ANY CHANGE OF INSULIN SHOULD BE MADE CAUTIOUSLY AND ONLY UNDER MEDICAL SUPERVISION. CHANGES IN STRENGTH, MANUFACTURER, TYPE (E.G., REGULAR, NPH, ANALOG), SPECIES, OR METHOD OF MANUFACTURE MAY RESULT IN THE NEED FOR A CHANGE IN DOSAGE. SOME PATIENTS TAKING HUMULIN® (HUMAN INSULIN, rDNA ORIGIN) MAY REQUIRE A CHANGE IN DOSAGE FROM THAT USED WITH OTHER INSULINS. IF AN ADJUSTMENT IS NEEDED, IT MAY OCCUR WITH THE FIRST DOSE OR DURING THE FIRST SEVERAL WEEKS OR MONTHS. DIABETES Insulin is a hormone produced by the pancreas, a large gland that lies near the stomach. This hormone is necessary for the body’s correct use of food, especially sugar. Diabetes occurs when the pancreas does not make enough insulin to meet your body’s needs. To control your diabetes, your doctor has prescribed injections of insulin products to keep your blood glucose at a near–normal level. You have been instructed to test your blood and/or your urine regularly for glucose. Studies have shown that some chronic complications of diabetes such as eye disease, kidney disease, and nerve disease can be significantly reduced if the blood sugar is maintained as close to normal as possible. The American Diabetes Association recommends that if your pre–meal glucose levels are consistently above 130 mg/dL or your hemoglobin A1c (HbA1c) is more than 7%, you should talk to your doctor. A change in your diabetes therapy may be needed. If your blood tests consistently show below–normal glucose levels, you should also let your doctor know. Proper control of your diabetes requires close and constant cooperation with your doctor. Despite diabetes, you can lead an active and healthy life if you eat a balanced diet, exercise regularly, and take your insulin injections as prescribed by your doctor. Always keep an extra supply of insulin as well as a spare syringe and needle on hand. Always wear diabetic identification so that appropriate treatment can be given if complications occur away from home.";
    string[] sentences = Regex.Split(temp, @"(?<!\w\.\w.)(?<!(Dr|Esq|Hon|Jr|Sr|Mr|Mrs|Ms|Messrs|Mmes|Msgr|Prof|Rev|Rt|Sr|St|Ltd|Col|Gen|Cpl|[A-Z][a-z]?)\.)(?<=\.|\?)\s");
    List<string> result = getBetween(sentences);
    myRichTextBox.Lines = result.ToArray(); // This will write to your rich text box
}
public static List<string> getBetween(string[] sentences)
{
    string key = "blood";
    List<string> results = new List<string>();
    foreach (string sentence in sentences)
    {
        if (sentence.Contains(key))
            results.Add(sentence);
    }
    return results;
}
```

Comment: @L.B Increased Regex efficiency. Let me know what breaks now.

Comment: `Blah blah. "It costs $2.5M" said Dr. House. Blah blah`. You can even remove `"`s . At the end, we can end up with a one page long regex :)

Comment: @L.B `House.` is what breaks it. Because it ends with a proper name.

Comment: But you find 2 sentences... It should be 3. Don't think I  say your solution is bad

Comment: @L.B I'm aware of that. It fails to split at `House.` when it should. It's catching `House.` in `(?<![A-Z][a-z]+\.)`. Working on a fix now.

Comment: @L.B Updated. Little more hardcoded than anticipated but works for now. I can keep adding titles and abbreviations to it and it will get more and more efficient.

Comment: `string source = "What is the result of blue+green?\n1. cyan\n2. black";` 3 or 4 sentences? (you can replace \n with \r\n if you want) :)

Comment: Maybe 1. but definitely not 4. I think It is good time to refer my first comment...

Comment: BTW: Don't get me wrong... I'll upvote your answer.. What i am trying to say is, it is not as easy as it sounds.....

Comment: Oh, I 100% agree. But this is fun haha. I'll update in the morning.

Comment: It isn't possible, though. Not to be a downer, but think of the sentences "I went to see Dr. House and he helped me walk again." and "I went to see the Dr. House helped me walk again." The first is one sentence, the second is two, but the second even though having a name, the Dr. refers to the first sentence, then you refer to the person as House in the second. You can only get close, unless you have a super complex engine to solve this, there's no point going farther than splitting on common elements :P and that's not even going into the differences in say British English vs American English.

Comment: I do agree that it most likely is impossible, but I don't necessarily agree those examples are accurate uses of the abbreviated Dr. I don't think Dr. can be used in a grammatically legal manner outside of it being used as a title.

Answer (score 0):

Split the string into sentences and then loop through the sentences.  Here is a quick take:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var strSource = "INFORMATION FOR THE PATIENT 10 mL Vial (1000 Units per vial) WARNINGS THIS LILLY HUMAN INSULIN PRODUCT DIFFERS FROM ANIMAL–SOURCE INSULINS BECAUSE IT IS STRUCTURALLY IDENTICAL TO THE INSULIN PRODUCED BY YOUR BODY’S PANCREAS AND BECAUSE OF ITS UNIQUE MANUFACTURING PROCESS. ANY CHANGE OF INSULIN SHOULD BE MADE CAUTIOUSLY AND ONLY UNDER MEDICAL SUPERVISION. CHANGES IN STRENGTH, MANUFACTURER, TYPE (E.G., REGULAR, NPH, ANALOG), SPECIES, OR METHOD OF MANUFACTURE MAY RESULT IN THE NEED FOR A CHANGE IN DOSAGE. SOME PATIENTS TAKING HUMULIN® (HUMAN INSULIN, rDNA ORIGIN) MAY REQUIRE A CHANGE IN DOSAGE FROM THAT USED WITH OTHER INSULINS. IF AN ADJUSTMENT IS NEEDED, IT MAY OCCUR WITH THE FIRST DOSE OR DURING THE FIRST SEVERAL WEEKS OR MONTHS. DIABETES Insulin is a hormone produced by the pancreas, a large gland that lies near the stomach. This hormone is necessary for the body’s correct use of food, especially sugar. Diabetes occurs when the pancreas does not make enough insulin to meet your body’s needs. To control your diabetes, your doctor has prescribed injections of insulin products to keep your blood glucose at a near–normal level. You have been instructed to test your blood and/or your urine regularly for glucose. Studies have shown that some chronic complications of diabetes such as eye disease, kidney disease, and nerve disease can be significantly reduced if the blood sugar is maintained as close to normal as possible. The American Diabetes Association recommends that if your pre–meal glucose levels are consistently above 130 mg/dL or your hemoglobin A1c (HbA1c) is more than 7%, you should talk to your doctor. A change in your diabetes therapy may be needed. If your blood tests consistently show below–normal glucose levels, you should also let your doctor know. Proper control of your diabetes requires close and constant cooperation with your doctor. Despite diabetes, you can lead an active and healthy life if you eat a balanced diet, exercise regularly, and take your insulin injections as prescribed by your doctor. Always keep an extra supply of insulin as well as a spare syringe and needle on hand. Always wear diabetic identification so that appropriate treatment can be given if complications occur away from home.";
            string[] strEnd = { ". ","? ","! " };
            var sentences = strSource.Split(strEnd,StringSplitOptions.None);
            var output = new StringBuilder();
            foreach (var sentence in sentences)
            {
                if (sentence.ToLower().Contains("blood"))
                {
                    output.AppendLine(sentence);
                }
            }
            Console.Write(output.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, I will try it, and I'll let you know if it working.

Comment: Extracting sentences from a string is not so easy. For ex `House first saw his eventual best friend Dr. James Wilson .....` (from wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_House)

Comment: Agreed, capturing sentences isn't easy. But if the data is from a fixed domain then you can get close enough for now.

Comment: @LarrySmithmier, I did it but in the if instead of Printing it, I added it into a string, and than I put the string into a richTextBox and for some reason the whole original string was shown there.

Comment: I updated it to use a string builder to build into a single string.  I have not pulled the base string back to get the end character back, but that could also be done by pulling the found substring from the original string.